# Is it possible to configure Quartz instances to only handle certain jobgroups?

Tags: quartz-scheduler

I have two web applications living on the same Tomcat installation, in which I would like to implement Quartz 1.x such that each web app only serves a single jobgroup in a shared Quartz data store.

Is it possible to configure a Quartz instance to serve (or ignore) specific group set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, but you can create multiple quartz instances, and only put certain job groups in each (and then it will of course only fire certain job groups).

Comment: This was/is my fallback, I just wanted to make sure I wasn't missing anything.  Thanks.